# Adding without using a + or - sign

Tags: math, code-challenge

There have been many "Do __ without *_*_" challenges before, but I hope that this is one of the most challenging.

### The Challenge

You are to write a program that takes two natural numbers (whole numbers > 0) from STDIN, and prints the sum of the two numbers to STDOUT. The challenge is that you must use as few `+` and `-` signs as possible. You are not allowed to use any sum-like or negation functions.

**Examples**

input

```
123
468
```

output

```
591
```

input

```
702
720
```

output

```
1422
```

**Tie Breaker:**
If two programs have the same number of `+` and `-` characters, the winner is the person with fewer `/` `*` `(` `)` `=` `.` `,` and `0-9` characters.

**Not Allowed:** Languages in which the standard addition/subtraction and increment/decrement operators are symbols other than `+` or `-` are not allowed. This means that Whitespace the language is not allowed.

Comment: Perhaps this challenge was a lot easier than I thought it would be, especially in other languages, where there are sum() functions. I have to fix this.

Comment: Just to clarify, this challenge does not care about code length right? Only the number of `+`,`-` and tie breaker characters? ...or do you need to change the rules again :-)

Comment: @Tommy No, it does not.

Comment: Concatenating strings works?

Comment: Are languages allowed that don't have arithmetic operators at all?  I *think* that last sentence permits them, but it's not completely clear.

Comment: Next challenge would be "Comparing two numbers without any of ><+-*/%&|"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Perl (no +/-, no tie-breakers, 29 chars)

```
s!!xx!;s!x!$"x<>!eg;say y!!!c
```

As a bonus, you can make the code sum more than two numbers by adding more `x`s to the `s!!xx!`.

Alternatively, here are two 21-char solutions with 1 and 3 tie-breakers respectively

```
say length$"x<>.$"x<>

say log exp(<>)*exp<>
```

Note: These solutions use the `say` function, available since Perl 5.10.0 with the `-E` command line switch or with `use 5.010`.  See the [edit history of this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/4047/revisions) for versions that work on older perls.

---

How does the solution with no tie-breakers work?

- `s!!xx!` is a [regexp replacement operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualgcer), operating by default on the `$_` variable, which replaces the empty string with the string `xx`.  (Usually `/` is used as the regexp delimiter in Perl, but really almost any character can be used.  I chose `!` since it's not a tie-breaker.)  This is just a fancy way of prepending `"xx"` to `$_` — or, since `$_` starts out empty (undefined, actually), it's really a way to write `$_ = "xx"` without using the equals sign (and with one character less, too).
- `s!x!$"x<>!eg` is another regexp replacement, this time replacing each `x` in `$_` with the value of the expression `$" x <>`.  (The `g` switch specifies global replacement, `e` specifies that the replacement is to be evaluated as Perl code instead of being used as a literal string.)  `$"` is a [special variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$LIST_SEPARATOR) whose default value happens to be a single space; using it instead of `" "` saves one char.  (Any other variable known to have a one-character value, such as `$&` or `$/`, would work equally well here, except that using `$/` would cost me a tie-breaker.)

  The `<>` [line input operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators), in scalar context, reads one line from standard input and returns it.  The `x` before it is the Perl [string repetition operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators), and is really the core of this solution: it returns its left operand (a single space character) repeated the number of times given by its right operand (the line we just read as input).
- `y!!!c` is just an obscure way to (ab)use the [transliteration operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr) to count the characters in a string (`$_` by default, again).  I could've just written `say length`, but the obfuscated version is one character shorter. :)

Comment: +1 - awsome and totally unreadable ;-) This seems to be the perfect answer since the character count doesn't matter in this challenge.

Comment: @Tommy, there are other perfect answers too. Maybe we should push for character count to be the final tie-breaker.

Comment: @Peter: I sort of assumed it already was, by default.

Comment: if character count is the final tie breaker, and many entries exist tied for zero in the other categories, doesn't this just become `code-golf` with some source restrictions?

Answer (score 54):

## R (24 characters)

```
length(sequence(scan()))
```

What this does:

- `scan` reads input from STDIN (or a file)
- `sequence` generates integer sequences starting from 1 and concatenates the sequences.  For example, `sequence(c(2, 3))` results in the vector `1 2 1 2 3`
- `length` calculates the number of elements in the concatenated vector

Example 1:

```
> length(sequence(scan()))
1: 123
2: 468
3:
Read 2 items
[1] 591
```

Example 2:

```
> length(sequence(scan()))
1: 702
2: 720
3:
Read 2 items
[1] 1422
```

Comment: Very clever, good job.

Comment: This blows my mind

Comment: +/- and above mentioned tie-breakers are interesting, not characters.

Comment: How does it calculate length? without using any addition? If so, I'd be surprised.

Comment: @TemPora The question only restricts the code in the answer, not the operations done behind the scenes. We're not going to restrict the question so the underlying computer architecture cannot increment a register.

Answer (score 18):

### D

```
main(){
    int a,b;
    readf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    while(b){a^=b;b=((a^b)&b)<<1;}
    write(a);
}
```

bit twiddling for the win

as a bonus the compiled code doesn't contain a add operation (can't speak for the readf call though)

Answer (score 13):

## Python 2, 43 bytes

```
print len('%s%s'%(input()*'?',input()*'!'))
```

Comment: Very inventive, but you might want to change the character used in the string to something other than a tie-breaker such as "~"

Comment: Thanks for the advice Alex, I had already forgotten about the tie-breaker rule.

Comment: `print sum(input(),input())`

Comment: razpeitia: I think sum is a "sum-like" function and thus not allowed.

Answer (score 10):

## [Seed](https://github.com/TryItOnline/seed), <s>3904</s> <s>3846</s> 11 bytes, 0 +/-, 10 tie breakers

```
4 141745954
```

Comment: Next up: the self-hosted version of seed LOL!!

Answer (score 8):

C (32bit only)

```
int main(int ac, char *av) {
    scanf("%d\n%d", &ac, &av);
    return printf("%d\n", &av[ac]);
}
```

Pointer arithmetic is just as good.
How does it match the requirements?
* No `+` or `-`
* No `/`, `=`, `.`, `0`-`9`
* Only 3 pairs of parenthesis, which seems to me minimal (you need `main`, `scanf`, `printf`).
* One `*` (the pointer approach requires it).
* Four `,` (could save one by defining normal variables, not `ac,av`)

Answer (score 8):

### C++ 0 +/-, 3 tie-breakers

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#define WAX (
#define WANE )
#define SPOT .

int main WAX WANE {
    unsigned x;
    unsigned y;
    std::cin >> x >> y;
    std::vector<int> v WAX x WANE;
    std::vector<int> u WAX y WANE;
    for WAX auto n : u WANE {
        v SPOT push_back WAX n WANE;
    }
    std::cout << v SPOT size WAX WANE;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

#### GolfScript

No +/- or tie-breakers:

```
# Twiddle some bits to get a few small integers
[]!~abs:two~abs:three!:zero~:minusone;

~[two base minusone%\two base minusone%]zip
zero:c;
{
    # Stack holds [x y] or [x] with implicit y is zero
    # Half adder using x y c: want to end up with sum on stack and carry back in c
    [~c zero]three<zero$
    ~^^\
    $~;:c;;
}%
[~c]minusone%two base
```

Much simpler version with two tie-breaker characters, using the same list-concatenation trick that other people are using:

```
~[\]{,~}%,
```

I'm assuming that GolfScript isn't disqualified for having `)` as an increment operator, as I'm not actually using it.

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, 0+2

```
import Monad
main = join $ fmap print $ fmap length $ fmap f $ fmap lines getContents
f x = join $ flip replicate [] `fmap` fmap read x
```

This uses no `+` or `-` characters, and only two `=` from the set of tie breaker characters, one of which is mandatory for binding `main`. The sum is done by concatenating lists of the appropriate lengths.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't see anyone do it the Electrical Engineering way, so here's my take (in ruby):

```
def please_sum(a, b)
    return (a&b !=0)? please_sum( ((a&b)<<1) , a^b ):a^b
end
```

It is a little bit ugly, but it gets the job done.  The two values are compared by a bitwise `AND`.  If they don't have any bits in common, there is no "carry" into the next binary column, so the addition can be completed by bitwise `XOR`ing them.  If there is a carry, you have to add the carry to the bitwise `XOR`.  Here's a little ruby script I used to make sure my digital logic was not too rusty:

```
100.times do
    a=rand 10
    b=rand 10
    c=please_sum(a,b)
    puts "#{a}+#{b}=#{c}"
    end
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT** This was posted BEFORE the rules changed to disallow `sum`...

The R language: No calls to `+` or `-`... And 9 tie-breaker characters!

```
sum(as.numeric(readLines(n=2)))
```

Example:

```
> sum(as.numeric(readLines(n=2)))
123
456
[1] 579
```

The `[1] 579` is the answer 579 (the `[1]` is to keep track of where in the result vector your are since in R all values are vectors - in this case of length 1)

Note that R has `+` operators just like most languages - it just so happens that it has `sum` too that sums up a bunch of vectors.

In this case, `readLines` returns a string vector of length 2. I then coerce it to numeric (doubles) and sum it up...

Just to show some other features of R:

```
> 11:20 # Generate a sequence
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

> sum(1:10, 101:110, pi)
[1] 1113.142
```

Comment: +1 For making me have to change the rules to outlaw the sum() function.

Comment: @PhiNotPi - Changing the rules?! That's cheating! :-) ...But you should probably say "sum-like functions" or I'll just use `colSums` instead... Maybe also outlaw "negation-like functions" while your at it...

Comment: I'm going to take your advice. From what I can tell, everyone (including me) on this site loves to point out loopholes in the rules.

Answer (score 5):

## The R language

New rules, new answer, same language. No calls to `+` or `-`

**UPDATE** Using `scan`, it drops to 11 tie-breaker characters (and 27 characters in all).

```
as.numeric(scan())%*%c(1,1)
```

Original: 13 tie-breaker characters!

```
as.numeric(readLines(n=2)) %*% c(1,1)
```

Example:

```
> as.numeric(readLines(n=2)) %*% c(1,1)
123
456
     [,1]
[1,]  579
```

This time the result is achieved by matrix multiplication. The answer is displayed as a 1x1 matrix.

Comment: There's nothing that I can do to outlaw this. Perhaps R is just good at this challenge, since it is mostly mathematics-based. Or maybe this challenge is just easy.

Comment: +1 Nice.  You can make this even shorter with `scan()` instead of `readlines(n=2)`

Comment: @Andrie - yes, but then you rely on the user entering exactly two numbers... Which is OK for this challenge I guess...

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, 0 `+`/`-`, <s>6</s> 2 tie-breakers (`=`)

### (does not use the string/list concatenation trick)

```
main = interact f
f x = show $ log $ product $ map exp $ map read $ lines x
```

Comment: You can eliminate all the dots at the expense of an extra = by replacing the composition: instead of "f.g.h" write "a where a x = f$g$h x"

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 <strike>4</strike> bytes, 0 `+`/`-`

```
F>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fze7/f3MjAy4gBgA)

Apologies if I misunderstood this challenge, but I was
surprised there was no 05AB1E answer. Shortest answer in
this language I could come up with that doesn't use + or
the built in sum function.

Explanation:

```
 F   #Loop A many times
  >  #Increment B
     #(Implicit output)
```

*-2 Bytes thanks to Grimy.*

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>64</strike> 62 bytes

Without relying on hidden summations in other functions.

```python
x=int(input());y=int(input())
while y:x,y=x^y,(x&y)*2
print(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8I2M69EIzOvoLREQ1PTuhKFy1WekZmTqlBpVaFTaVsRV6mjUaFWqallxFVQBFJWofn/v7ERl4kJAA)

Comment: by replacing the first line by `x=int(input());y=int(input())` you save 2 tie breakers (and without loosing any byte). You should also redo your TIO link, to make it mach your post

Answer (score 5):

## Excel, <s>(25, 8) (22, 6)</s> 13, 4 tie-breakers

Inputs are `A1`, `A2`.

```
=2*MEDIAN(A:A
^^^      ^
```

Because `MEDIAN` is shorter than `AVERAGE` and `AGGREGATE`.

Answer (score 4):

### Javascript (17 tie-breaker characters)

```
eval('걢갽거걲걯걭거건갨걡갽거걲걯걭거건갨걹갽걦걵걮걣건걩걯걮갨걡갩걻걣갽걮걥걷갠걕걩걮건갸걁걲걲걡걹갨걡갩갻걦걯걲갨걩갠걩걮갠걣갩걩걦갨걩갽갽걾걾걩갩걸갮거걵걳걨갨갱갩걽갬걸갽걛걝갩갩갻걹갨걡갩갻걹갨걢갩갻걡걬걥걲건갨걸갮걬걥걮걧건걨갩갻'['split']('')['map'](function(_){return String['fromCharCode'](_['charCodeAt'](~~[])^0xac00)})['join'](''))
```

:P ("Obfuscated" to reduce number of tie-breaker characters. Internally, it's
`b=prompt(a=prompt(y=function(a){c=new Uint8Array(a);for(i in c)if(i==~~i)x.push(1)},x=[]));y(a);y(b);alert(x.length);`
.)

Comment: Clever use of obfuscation! Love it!

Answer (score 4):

**Javascript, 56**

```
p=prompt;alert(Array(~~p()).concat(Array(~~p())).length)
```

Thanks to @JiminP on the ~~ tip! I'm going for least bytes, so the 1 byte saving on the p=prompt; is still worth it. I understand your argument about tie-breaker chars, but to be honest wouldn't you rather the least bytes :-p

**Version, 69**

```
i=parseInt;p=prompt;alert(Array(i(p())).concat(Array(i(p()))).length)
```

Thanks to some feedback from @Ilmari and @JiminP, I've shaved 13 bytes off my original solution.

*Originally, 82*

```
i=parseInt;p=prompt;a=Array(i(p()));a.push.apply(a, Array(i(p())));alert(a.length)
```

Comment: That space after the comma is completely unnecessary; removing it gets you down to 81.

Comment: Using `concat` and put calculations in `alert` is shorter. `i=parseInt;p=prompt;alert(Array(i(p())).concat(Array(i(p()))).length)`   BTW, I didn't know that `Array(n)` returns an array with length `n`. The Google Chrome console gave me `[]` and I thought there was nothing...

Comment: Oh, since the important thing is tie-breaker characters, `p=prompt` is not good. And, `parseInt(x)` is almost equivalent to `~~x`. `alert(Array(~~prompt())['concat'](Array(~~prompt()))['length'])` (12 tie-breaker chars)  PS. I could use this as my entry, but that just gives me feeling of stealing.

Comment: ES6 version: `_=>Array(~~prompt``)["concat"](Array(~~prompt``))["length"]` with 7 TB

Answer (score 4):

### C

```
b[500];i;j;main(){scanf("%d%d",&i,&j);printf("%d\n",sprintf(b,"%*s%*s",i,"",j,""));
```

Answer (score 4):

### APL (no +/-, no tie breakers, 8 or 10 characters)

This entry is similar to the other ones that concatenate sequences generated from the input and find the length... but it's in APL, which can appear confusing even for a small problem like this. I used [Dyalog APL](http://www.dyalog.com), which offers a free educational license.

Code:

```
⍴⊃⍪⌿⍳¨⎕⎕
```

From right to left:

- Each quote-quad ( `⎕` ) requests input from the user and evaluates it.
- The each operator ( `¨` ) applies the index generator function (  `⍳` ) to each of the items in the array to its right.
- This flattens the resulting array of arrays into one array. The input array is reduced to a flat list by the reduction operator ( `/` ), which folds the array using the concatenation function ( `,` ). For the sake of this challenge, the one-dimensional reduction operator ( `⌿` ) is used, along with the concatenation operator along the first axis ( `⍪` ).
- As a result of using the reduction operator, the array is *enclosed*, which is like placing it in the bag; all we see on the outside is a bag, not its contents. The disclose operator ( `⊃` ) gives us the contents of the enclosed array (the bag).
- Finally, the shape-of function ( `⍴` ) gives us the lengths of the dimensions of an array. In this case, we have a one-dimensional array, so we obtain the number of items in the array, which is our result.

If we need to explicitly output the result, we can do so like this:

```
⎕←⍴⊃⍪⌿⍳¨⎕⎕
```

Comparable Python code, with corresponding APL symbols above:

```
import operator

⎕←     ⍴    ⌿        ⍪                 ¨              ⍳                ⎕        ⎕         ⊃
print (len (reduce (operator.__add__, [map (lambda n: range (1, n+1), [input(), input()])][0])))
```

I'd like to know if there's a shorter version possible in APL - another, simpler version I came up with that has more tie breakers (although still at 8 characters) is: `⍴(⍳⎕),⍳⎕`.

Comment: Does your index generator start at 1 or 0?

Answer (score 4):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 0 `+-` characters, 0 tiebreakers, 33 bytes

```
"e:"%"X:"%::%p"h:"%"Y:"%::%p&&  @
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/XynVSklVKQJIWFmpFihlgHiRUJ6amoKCw///5gZGCuZGBgA)

#### Explanation

Like @negative seven's Befunge answer, we generate `+` and `.` at runtime and put them onto the field to be executed. However, Befunge-93 does not include the `y` instruction, so we abuse the `%` modulo operator instead.

```
"e:"%                                            # Calculate 101 ('e') mod 58 (':') to get 43 ('+')
     "X:"%                                       # Calculate 88 ('X') mod 58 to get 30
          ::%                                    # Calculate 30 mod 30 to get 0
             p                                   # Put character 43 ('+') at position (30, 0)
              "h:"%                              # Calculate 104 ('h') mod 58 to get 46 ('.')
                   "Y:"%                         # Calculate 89 ('Y') mod 58 to get 31
                        ::%                      # Calculate 31 mod 31 to get 0
                           p                     # Put character 46 ('.') at position (31, 0)
                            &&                   # Get two numbers from STDIN
                              (changed to '+')   # Add the numbers together
                               (changed to '.')  # Output the result
                                @                # End the program
```

Answer (score 4):

## Scala 2.12, 20 bytes, 0 +/- signs

```
readInt\u002breadInt
```

The unicode literal is just turned into a `+` before compilation

Comment: This is in no way cheating. In fact, this answer emphasizes the very reason why "do X without Y" is now discouraged.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `as`, 0 bytes

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=as&code=&inputs=12%0A24&header=&footer=)

The `a` flag takes newline separated inputs as a list, and the `s` flag sums the top of the stack.

## Non-trivial `a`, <s><sup>4</sup></s> 2 bytes

*-2 bytes because I realized the challenge guarantees 2 number input.*

```
ṁd
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=a&code=%E1%B9%81d&inputs=12%0A24&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
    # 'a' flag - take newline separated inputs as a list
ṁ   # Mean of inputs
 d  # Multiply by 2
    # Implicit output
```

Effectively calculates `((a + b) / 2) * 2`, which is equivalent to `a + b`. The previous version worked for any amount of numbers, but it turns out the challenge specifies taking 2 numbers as input, so this works fine.

Answer (score 2):

### Shell, 52

```
read a
read b
(seq 1 $a;seq 1 $b)|wc|awk '{print$1}'
```

This is basically the [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4765078/149391) I gave for another problem.

Comment: Similar:  `xargs -n1 jot | wc -l` which takes the same `-` reduction `awk` but I can't see how to avoid it in the `xargs`

Comment: +/- and above mentioned tie-breakers are interesting, not characters.

Answer (score 2):

### C

```
a,b;A(int a,int b){return a&b?A(a^b,(a&b)<<1):a^b;}
main(){scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);printf("%d\n",A(a,b));}
```

Comment: I count 20 tie breakers... Am I right?

Comment: 22 tie breakers: 0 `/*=.`, 7 `(`, 7 `)`, 7 `,`, 1 `[0-9]`

Answer (score 2):

**C#**

It's not the shortest by any stretch:

```
private static int getIntFromBitArray(BitArray bitArray)
{
    int[] array = new int[1];
    bitArray.CopyTo(array, 0);
    return array[0];
}

private static BitArray getBitArrayFromInt32(Int32 a)
{
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
    return new BitArray(bytes);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BitArray first = getBitArrayFromInt32(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
    BitArray second = getBitArrayFromInt32(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
    BitArray result = new BitArray(32);

    bool carry = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
        if (first[i] && second[i] && carry)
        {
            result[i] = true;
        }
        else if (first[i] && second[i])
        {
            result[i] = false;
            carry = true;
        }
        else if (carry && (first[i] || second[i]))
        {
            result[i] = false;
            carry = true;
        }
        else
        {
            result[i] = carry || first[i] || second[i];
            carry = false;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(getIntFromBitArray(result));
}
```

Comment: That's exhausting, Matthew.

Comment: Is this a literal full adder circuit implemented in a program?

Answer (score 2):

## J, <s>15</s> 7 chars, 1 tie breaker, incomplete program

This is my J attempt. It is not a full program, because I have not yet figured out how to write one. Just put that line in a script to get the function `p` that can be used for adding an arbitrary amount of numbers. It is a monad and takes a list of numbers to add (such as `p 1 2 3 4`):

```
p=:#@#~
```

The idea is very simple. The function is written in tacit aka pointless style. Here is a pointed definition:

```
p=:3 :'##~y'
```

Read from right to left. In the tacit version, `@` composes the parts of the function. (like a ∘ in mathematics [(f∘g)(x) = f(g(x)])

- `y` is the parameter of `p`.
- `~` makes a verb reflexive. For some verb `m`, `m~ a` is equal to `a m a`.
- `#` (copy, `a#b`): Each element in `a` is replicated `i` times, where `i` is the element at the same index as the current element of `a` of `b`. Thus, `#~` replicates an item `n` `n` times.
- `#` (count, `#b`): Counts the number of elements in `b`.

Conclusion: J is awsome and less readable than Perl (that makes it even more awsome)

### Edits

- 15 -> 7 using `#` instead of `i.`. Yeah! Less chars than golfscript.

### More of a program

This one queries for input, but it still isn't a full program: (13 chars, 3 breakers)

```
##~".1!:1<#a:
```

Comment: J is definitely awesome, but believe me, you can't just leave out the parsing part of the problem when you solve challenges with it ;-)

Comment: @J B Well, you can use the builtin function toJ, but I keep getting domain errors.

Answer (score 2):

## C#,

Program works on 1 line; separated on multiple lines to avoid horizontal scrolling.

```
using C=System.Console;
class A{
static void Main(){
int a,b,x,y;
a=int.Parse(C.ReadLine());
b=int.Parse(C.ReadLine());
do{x=a&b;y=a^b;a=x<<1;b=y;}while(x>0);
C.WriteLine(y);
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>26</s> 25 bytes, <s>7</s> 5 tiebreakers

-1 byte, -2 tiebreakers thanks to @Nahuel Fouilleul.

```sh
set {1..$1} {1..$2}
<<<$#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanxvzi1RKHaUE9PxbAWQhvVctnY2Kgo/9fk4kpTsDRQMDb5DwA)

---

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>62</s> 60 bytes, 0 tiebreakers

-2 bytes because `repeat foo` evaluates `foo` in arithmetic mode.

```sh
read a b
{repeat a;printf x;repeat b;printf x}|read x
<<<$#x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/KDUxRSFRIYmruii1IDWxRCHRuqAoM68kTaHCGiqSBBeprQErr@CysbFRUa74/9/SQMHYBAA)

Comment: [25 bytes, 5 tiebreakers](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanxvzi1RKHaUE9PxbAWQhvVctnY2Kgo/9fk4kpTsDRQMDb5DwA "Zsh – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## C++, () only for `main`

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int a, b;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin >> b;


    unsigned int p = a ^ b;
    unsigned int g = a & b;

    unsigned int gg {g | p & g << 1};
    unsigned int pp {p & p << 1};

    unsigned int ggg {gg | pp & gg << 2};
    unsigned int ppp {pp | pp << 2};

    unsigned int gggg {ggg | ppp & ggg << 4};
    unsigned int pppp {ppp & ppp << 4};

    unsigned int ggggg {gggg | pppp & gggg << 8};
    unsigned int ppppp {pppp | pppp << 8};

    unsigned int gggggg {ggggg | ppppp & ggggg << 16};

    unsigned int result {a ^ b ^ gggggg << 1};
    std::cout << result;
}
```

Assumes 32-bit unsigned ints. Very ugly code to remove tiebreak characters. Emulates a Kogge-Stone adder.

Answer (score 2):

## Octave/MATLAB, 37 bytes

```Octave
f=@()e^(input(''));disp(log(f()*f()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/zdZBQzM1TiMzr6C0RENdXVPTOiWzuEAjJz9dI01DUwuINTX//zcx4jI2BgA)

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'd recommend you split these up into two answers so that users can vote and improve them separately.

Comment: [31](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/zdZBQzM1TiMzr6C0RENdXVPTOic/XSNNQ1MLiDX//zcx4jI2BgA) by using the implicit output

Comment: Also, your answer does not actually work in Matlab since it does not have `e` defined. I believe the shortest answer in Matlab (at least with this approach) is, therefore, [32](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/zdZBQzO1okAjM6@gtERDXV1T0zonP10jTUNTC4g1//83MeIyNgYA).

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3

```python
import numpy as n;i=lambda:n.e**int(input());print(int(n.log(i()*i())))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCGvNLegUiGxWCHPOtM2JzE3KSXRKk8vVUsrM69EIzOvoLREQ1PTuqAIwi3RyNPLyU/XyNTQ1AJiIPj/38SIy9gYAA)

Comment: I was trying to remove the log and e but forgot about the original restrictions... :( Reverted now.

Comment: Okay it's working now. You should probably include the link in your answer: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1chrzS3oFIhM7cgv6hEIVUnJz@dK9M2JzE3KSXRKlVLKzOvRCMzr6C0RENT07qgCMIt0QAq08jU0NQCYiD4/9/EiMvUGAA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Welcome! Please consider adding an explanation or a link to an online interpreter. Code-only answers tend to be automatically flagged as low-quality.

Answer (score 2):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 8 bytes

```
IRmIRmlh
```

Minus one byte!, I figured out that I didn't need to take both inputs first

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/3zMoF4hygCxzAyMucyMDAA)

**Previous answer, 9 bytes**

```
IIRfrRflh
```

Explanation below

```
II        take both inputs
  Rm      Pop and repeat that number of times, pushing -1
    r     Reverse stack (to get the first num on top)
     Rm   Pop and repeat that number of times, pushing -1
       lh Push length of stack, and output as a number halting
```

Basically what I did was count it all out in unary, it would only take a few more bytes to expand it to be able to handle more than two numbers

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39MzKLcoKDcHyDQ3MOIyNzIAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 48 bytes, 12 tie-breakers

```
a=>b=>"0".repeat(a).concat("0".repeat(b)).length
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 26 bytes

### Tiebreakers: 11?

```js
a=>b=>Math.log2(2**a*2**b)
```

Takes input as `(a)(b)`.
Uses the power index rule \$a^{x+y}=a^{x}a^{y}\$ and returns the \$log_2(2^{a}2^{b})\$ which is basically \$log_2(2^{a+b}) = a+b\$.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 0 +/-, 0 tiebreakers (5 bytes)

```
#JoXg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9f2Ss/Iv3///@GJv9NjAA)

#### Explanation

A string-concatenation approach:

```
    g  List containing the command-line args
  oX   For each arg, make a string of that many 1s (o is a variable preinitialized to 1)
 J     Join the list into a single string
#      Get its length
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 0 +/-, 2 tie-breaker (144 bytes)

```python
exec`["%c"%[ord(i)^True<<True<<True<<True][False]for i in"""xzaf| :""afx}| !":""afx}| !'':!&ja|Wdmfo|` !"""]`[True<<True::True<<True<<True|True]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU9db8IwDHzvrwiWWJLBYHRjbBW87hcg8RB1apa6WvhokNNK3ZT99q5FQyBeLNt3vjsfv6svV8atcTmuiHPeYoMmUzA0MFSOcmHlx5pqXC5va6re9d5jWjhiltkSAJofXQSWAOii@Q1sAJeW82Rwt9Vhkx8KF7IOA0gzdZFLkluDcHJpu1DRkWxZAaGv91WnP476lKIPLf8xbxxhD7F@OzGuLisBI5Cj6/kBzvy1RfZJqHdI/nTm64NQV1wr2fkzBtN7IVeT8eMsfnqevyxe3yCVURvPo9niDw)

#### How it works :

The general idea is to remove tie-breaker character of a non cheaty working solution. To do that I converted a solution by changing the 5th bit of each character.

Some tricks are used to avoid using tiebreaker character during the translation :

- `True` and `False` are evaluated by python as 1 and 0. Using that I can easyly create some usefull integers like 2, 5 and 8 in my solution without using `[0-9]`
- Parenthesis are bad (for this challenge at least). To replace them I used `[expression][False]` which return the first element of an 1-element array, using the []-priority over other operators.
- To join an array of char, the common technique is to use `"".join(my_array)` but it uses 3 tie-breakers. I instead uses `` `my_array`[2::5] `` which take the representation of the array and select only the wanted character by concatenating them.
- To get the ascii character from its interger representation, intead of using the built-in `chr(i)` (which uses 2 tie-breaker), I used `"%c"%i` wich does the same

In better understandable python, here is my solution :

```python
exec`["%c"%(ord(i)^8)for i in""" CODED_SOLUTION """]`[2::5]
```

with `CODED_SOLUTION` once decoded :

```python
print(2*input()*2**input()//2).bit_length()
```

which looks like my older solution (and which doesn't use any form of addition :p)

### Older Solution (7 tiebreaker, 50 bytes)

```python
print int.bit_length(True<<input()<<input()>>True)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NDoIwEITvPEWzp1YQBUXUAE/BzRijdZVGbEl/En36CkQNh012Z@abbPe2jZKp5@qKpQYA32khLeknvgh7alHebUNr7bAohOycpey/VNWgM99jwYiBRuNaS/YQBfhCToda9vUMVxoHiwxqzJWTlkIILJzec/jla4HkovH8QG1GzLgnPUyygpGb0kT0zxJYzCgr42iZpKt1tsm3OziywCd5kGYf)

The idea is to shift a `True` interpreted as `1` by python Xtimes and Ytimes then shift once the other way and take the len of the binary representation

### Cheated solution (45 bytes, 6 Tie-breaker)

I also have a cheated solution in 45 bytes:

```python
print eval("\x2binput()"*[True<<True][False])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxLDoIwFEXnrKJ5oxYQBUXUwNQVMEMGUJ@xEVvSj8HVoxBNmNzkfs7t3/auZDJydcVCA8DYayEtwVfTUbgMSStk7yxl4Feldpjnk9bVuekM1mz8Et5MgEbjOktOEHo4IKfTI/t1hiuNU0WmNOLKSUshABYs/Qr@@1IgaTU2D9Rmxox70mqxFYzclCaCCElg7VNWROEmTra7dJ8djlAzb4wzL0k/)

which evaluates the string `+input()+input()` but convert the char `+` by its hexadecimal representation.

the `[True<<True][False]` is equal to 2

### Other Ideas:

I had the idea to use `a=abs(~a)` to increment a by 1 but I didn't totaly managed to produce a working solution with that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 0 +/-, 2 Tie-breaker, (68 bytes)

```python
lambda x,y:A[f"{True<<x<<y:b}"[True:]]
class A:__class_getitem__=len
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFCp9LKMTpNqTqkqDTVxqbCxqbSKqlWKRrEtYqN5UrOSSwuVnC0io8Hs@LTU0syS1Jz4@Ntc1Lz/hcUZeaVaKRpGBnrGBppav4HAA)

`class A:__class_getitem__=len` allows me to replace `len(x)` by `A[x]`

### Old, 3 Tie-breaker, (40 bytes)

```python
lambda x,y:len(f"{True<<x<<y:b}"[True:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFCp9IqJzVPI02pOqSoNNXGpsLGptIqqVYpGsS1itX8X1CUmVeikaZhZKxjaKSp@R8A)

### Explanation :

- `True`in python is evaluated as 1 => `1`
- shift `x` times then `y` times => `4` => `32` (for x=2 and y=3)
- convert it to its string binary representation => `"100000"`
- remove the first char of the string => `"00000"`
- get the length => `5`

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure (44 chars)

```
(pr(#(count(concat(%)(%)))#(repeat(read)0)))
```

Edit: fixed to print on STDOUT instead of just returning sum.

Comment: +/- and above mentioned tie-breakers are interesting, not characters.

Answer (score 1):

### D

```
main(){
    int a,b;
    readf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    write((new int[a]~new int[b]).length);
}
```

this time using array lengths

Answer (score 1):

### Scala

- score:

  - +-  : 0
  - (). : 5+5+3=13

Code:

```
(List.fill (readInt) (1) ::: List.fill (readInt) (2)).size
```

- List.fill (4)(7) produces List (7, 7, 7, 7)
- a ::: b concatenates 2 Lists into one
- The rest should be obvious

Answer (score 1):

## K, 11

```
{#,[!x;!y]}
```

Same concatenation trick as the R solution. Reading right to left: Enumerate the two input variables, concatenate and then count.

Answer (score 1):

### [Keg](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Keg) (SBCS on Keg wiki)

Basically a port of the R answer.

```
¿¿Ï_"Ï_!.
```

### Explanation

```
¿¿#        Take 2 integer inputs
  Ï_"Ï_#   Generate 2 arrays the length of the integer inputs
       !.# Output the length of the stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>27</s> 42 bytes, 0 `+-`, <s>4</s> 1 secondary

<sup>Thanks to mazzy for saving a `+` and 4 secondaries</sup>

```powershell
$args|%{[int[]]$_*$_}|measure|select count
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V8lsSi9uEa1OjozryQ6NlYlXkslvrYmNzWxuLQotaY4NSc1uUQhOb80r@R/LReXmkqagqmCoQGXujqYbahg@B8A) or [Pretty Table for an extra 3 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V8lsSi9uEa1OjozryQ6NlYlXkslvrYmNzWxuLQotaY4NSc1uUQhOb80r6QmLed/LReXmkqagqmCoQGYYahg@B8A)

**-Or- adding four secondaries to save 19 bytes:**

## <s>32</s> 23 bytes, <s>1</s> 0 `+-`, <s>12</s> 5 secondaries

<sup>-9 bytes thanks to mazzy</sup>

```powershell
($args|%{,$_*$_}).count
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V9DJbEovbhGtVpHJV5LJb5WUy85vzSv5H8tF5eaSpqCqYKhAZhhqGD4HwA)

For each argument, we push `n` array elements (consisting of `[n]` but that's not important) to the pipeline which are grouped by the parens and then counted.

Comment: [23 bytes, 0 +-, 5 secondaries](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V9DJbEovbhGtVpHJV5LJb5WUy85vzSv5H8tF5eaSpqCqYKhAZhhqGD4HwA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: I'm sorry, this is NOT codegolf. [0 +-, 3 secondries, 27 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V8l0VYlsSi9uEa1WkclXkslvpZLJVHPOb80r@R/LReXmkqagqmCoQGYYahg@B8A "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy That's 4 by my count but thanks nonetheless :D

Comment: you are right. thanks. [0+-, 1 Tie Breaker, 42 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V8lsSi9uEa1OjozryQ6NlYlXkslvrYmNzWxuLQotaY4NSc1uUQhOb80r@R/LReXmkqagqmCoQGXuq6urjqYa6hg@B8A "PowerShell – Try It Online"). you could add `|fl` for a pretty format [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V8lsSi9uEa1OjozryQ6NlYlXkslvrYmNzWxuLQotaY4NSc1uUQhOb80r6QmLed/LReXmkqagqmCoQGYYahg@B8A "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby -na0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), no +/-, no tiebreakers, 60 bytes

```ruby
$F<<?a until~%r[
]&&$F::join[%r[a{#$`}a{#$'}]]
p$F::count ?a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X8XNxsY@UaE0ryQzp061KJorVk1Nxc3KKis/My8ayE@sVlZJqAWR6rWxsVwFILnkfKByBfvE//@NuUz@5ReUZObnFf/XzUs0AAA)

Actually harder than I thought, I'm almost certainly missing a trick.

Reads in the input, then adds `a` characters to the argument array until the array, when joined into a string, matches a regular expression that uses the two input numbers as quantifiers, then counts how many it added.

Syntax tricks include using `%r[]` instead of `//` for a regexp, and `::` instead `.` for a method call.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 0 +/-, 0 tie-breakers, 39 bytes

And fairly unreadable.

```ruby
p"#{"%#{"%ss%%%ss"%$F}"%%w[o o]}"::size
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BJuVpJFYSLi1VVgYSSqopbrZKqanl0vkJ@bK2SlVVxZlXq///mBkZc5kYG//ILSjLz84r/6@YlGgAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py), 0 `+-`, 1 tiebreaker

```
~{)
```

Input as a list. If taking the two inputs separated is mandatory, a trailing `ê` should be added (read entire STDIN input as integer-array).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/7@uWvP//2hDI2MdEzOLWK5ocwMjHXMjg1gA)

**Explanation:**

```python
~    # Push the value of the (implicit) input-list to the stack
 {   # Loop the top value amount of times
  )  #  And increase the other value once every iteration
     # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 46 bytes

```lua
print(load'return io.read"n"\x2Bio.read"n"'())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0QjJz8xRb0otaS0KE8hM1@vKDUxRSlPKabCyAnBU9fQ1Pz/39DImMvE1AwA)

#### How It Works

`load` loads a string and returns a function, we pass a hexadecimal to it and call the function.

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 11 bytes, 2 +-, 3 tie breaker

```
,>,[-<+>]<.
```

Sadly i can’t think up anyway of manipulating number without `+-`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fx04nWtdG2y7WRu//fwA)

Comment: If + and - are used, it is simply invalid.

Comment: @Razetime It's mentioned in question that use as few `+-` a possible

Comment: ah, it isn't too clear or exact about what's banned. I suppose it's ok

Comment: @Razetime This answer is bad anyway, I just can't think up anyway to use 1 `+-` only.

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 22 bytes, 0 +/-, 2 tiebreakers

```
lne^{\ans_0}e^{\ans_1}
```

Input numbers in the first two lines. I have to admit, I spent an embarrassing amount of time trying to go from the obvious 4 tiebreakers solution `[\ans_0,\ans_1].total` to a 2 tiebreakers solution. I considered many other interesting ideas to go from 3 to 2 (integrals, percent of, `{}` evaluates to 1, etc.), but at the end, it turned out to be very simple...

I'm pretty sure 2 tiebreakers is optimal for Desmos because a `0` and `1` are required to obtain input. Defining a function is even worse: You need `(`, `)` and `=`, which is 3 tiebreakers.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cngszbfqer)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 2 tie-breakers

```javascript
alert(`${``[`repeat`][`call`]`${prompt``}`}${``[`repeat`][`call`]`${prompt``}`}`[`length`])
```

Could I have made it shorter? Yes. But I find this version especially amusing.

Peculiarities:

- Only uses lowercase letters and the symbols `$` `[` `]` `` ` `` `{` `}`
- Uses no mathematical operators.
- Relies heavily on especially cryptic JavaScript features

Tricks used:

- `obj['prop']` instead of `obj.prop` to avoid using `.`
- tagged template literals to avoid using `(` `)` to call functions

  - `` func`string` `` evaluates to  `func(['string'])`
  - `` func`${ expression }` `` evaluates to `func(['', ''], expression)`
- `['', ''].toString()` produces `','`
- `''.repeat.call(',', value)` is equivalent to `','.repeat(value)`. This hack is used to turn the repeat function into one which takes the number of repeats as its second argument, so that we can use that function as a tag.

Edit: oops, forgot to alert the result. Uh, I'll just wrap that in an alert for now, feel free to suggest an improvement

Answer (score 0):

### Python

```
i=input
print eval('%d\x2b%d'%(i(),i()))
```

37 chars with a little bit of cheating :p

Answer (score 0):

**A very yucky C version**

Has no `+`, `-`, `/` or any digits. One use of `*` for a pointer type. The others (`()=,`) are needed a lot in the language itself.

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned char *ptr;

char
  y;

const size_t
  one = sizeof y;

unsigned char
  zero='a'^'a',
  a [] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  z [] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  x [] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

size_t plus_one (size_t i)
{
  ptr b=&a[one];
  memset (a,'x',sizeof a);
  b[i]=zero;
  return strlen(a);
}

size_t minus_one (size_t i)
{
  ptr b=&a[one];
  memset (a,'x',sizeof a);
  a[i]=zero;
  return strlen(b);
}

size_t minus_zero (size_t i)
{
  size_t p;
  for (p = zero ; z[p] ; p = plus_one (p))
  {
    i = minus_one(i);
  }
  return i;
}

unsigned char to_zero (unsigned char i)
{
  size_t p;
  for (p = one>>one ; x[p] ; p = plus_one (p))
  {
    i = (unsigned char) minus_one(i);
  }
  return i;
}

main (int argc, ptr argv [])
{
  ptr
    a = argv [argc>>one],
    b = argv [argc>>one<<one];

  size_t
    len_a = strlen (a),
    len_b = strlen (b),
    len = len_a > len_b ? len_a : len_b,
    o = plus_one(len),
    i,
    c=one>>one;

  ptr
    res=(ptr)malloc(plus_one(o));

  res[o]=zero;

  for (i = zero ; i < len ; i=plus_one(i))
  {
    size_t va;
    unsigned char r;

    va = (len_a > zero ? minus_zero (a[minus_one(len_a)]) <<one<<one<<one<<one : zero) | (len_b > zero ? minus_zero (b[minus_one (len_b)]) : zero);
    r = (c?"bcdefghijAuhjsadcdefghijABsadlkfdefghijABCvsxwerefghijABCDDNIWjsfghijABCDEOQJdccghijABCDEFIndDjlhijABCDEFGCnjndwijABCDEFGHsadXSkjABCDEFGHICSjshdABCDEFGHIJcbaCBA":"abcdefghijaswhHDbcdefghijAQWuciucdefghijABCOasdpdefghijABCCnjaskefghijABCDCIUdasfghijABCDEuoiDSAghijABCDEFCsalkjhijABCDEFGcapCPcijABCDEFGHCWEoerjABCDEFGHIkjIjIj") [va];
    c=r<'a';
    r&=~(one<<one<<one<<one<<one<<one);
    o=minus_one(o);
    res[o]=to_zero(r);

    if (len_a) len_a = minus_one (len_a);
    if (len_b) len_b = minus_one (len_b);
  }
  if(c) 
  {
    o=minus_one(o);
    res[o]=to_zero('B');
  }
  printf("%s\n",&res[o]);
  free (res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Common Lisp

Always surprising for such a verbose language.

```
((lambda(n m)(princ(length(append(make-list n)(make-list m)))))(read)(read))
```

Answer (score 0):

### VBA - No +/-, 7 tie-breakers

`+`,`-`,`/`,`*`,`,`,`.`,`0-9` = 0
`(` = 3 (3 total pairs)
`)` = 3
`=` = 1

```vb
Function a(b)
    For Each c In b
        a = a & Space(c)
    Next
    MsgBox Len(a)
End Function
```

Takes an array of natural numbers as an argument. This will actually add more than just 2 values, if provided, as well as return the value of a single argument.

**Older versions**

---

`+`,`-`,`/`,`*`,`=`,`.`,`0-9` = 0
`(` = 4 (4 total pairs)
`)` = 4
`,` = 1

```vb
Function a(b, c)
MsgBox Len(Space(b) & Space(c))
End Function
```

`+`,`-`,`/`,`*`,`=`,`.`,`0-9` = 0
`(` = 4 (4 total pairs)
`)` = 4
`,` = 3

```vb
Sub a(b,c)
MsgBox Len(String(b," ") & String(c," "))
End Sub
```

---

`+`,`-`,`/`,`*`,`.` = 0
`=` = 4
`(` = 2 (2 total pairs)
`)` = 2
`0-9` = 2
`,` = 1

```vb
Sub d(e,f)
For g=1 To e:h=h & " ":Next
For g=1 To f:h=h & " ":Next
MsgBox Len(h)
End Sub
```

Comment: Character count technically doesn't matter in this challenge. You have no `-+`, and you have 11 tie breakers. This puts you above any solution that has a `-+` character, and below any solution with no `-+` with fewer tie breakers.

Comment: So, I am tied with (as one example) [Uri Goren's answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4613/3862), correct? He has no +/-, but 11 tie-breakers.

Comment: Yes, you are tied with him.

Answer (score 0):

## C #, 26 tiebreakers

```
+/- : 0
=   : 2
.   : 6 
()  : 18
```

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Func<int[]> f=()=>new int[int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())];
        Console.Write(f().Concat(f()).Count());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 22 chars

```php
echo array_sum($argv);
```

**Documentation**: [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-sum.php) and [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.argv.php)
**Usage**: `php -r 'echo array_sum($argv);' 5 6` will output `11`.

Comment: +/- and above mentioned tiebreakers are interesting, not chars.

Answer (score 0):

### APL (10, 3 tie-breakers)

```
⎕←⍴(⍳⎕),⍳⎕
```

Comment: 10x +/-?  Chars arn't interesting, just +/- and the tie-breakers.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3 - 159 characters | ().,*/= count: 39

A little long, but I felt like doing it HDL-style.

```
a,b,c,d=int(input()),int(input()),0,0;l=max(a,b,key=int.bit_length)
for i in range(len(bin(l<<1)[2:])):
 e=a>>i&1;f=b>>i&1;c|=(e^f^d)<<i;d=e&f|d&(e^f)
print(c)
```

Comment: +/- tiebreakers are interesting, not characters.

Comment: @userunknown: What's wrong with characters?

Comment: Characters are counted in CodeGolf tagged questions. If a reader doesn't read the question again, he will get the impression that character count is important and probably make a misguided vote based on that assumption. So the rules say: No (+|-). In Tiebreak digits, ().,*/= are important. You should include that number in your answer, so that not every visitor has to count them himself.

Comment: @userunknown: Oh, right.

Answer (score 0):

### C# 141 characters 27 tiebreakers

```
+/- : 0
=   : 0
.   : 9 
()  : 18


Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Range(1,int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()))
.Concat(Enumerable.Range(1,int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())))
.Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 42

```
a,b=input()
print eval("~-"*a+"~-"*b+"0")
```

Seven tie breakers, but those are string operations

Answer (score 0):

C#, 12 tiebreakers (), 3 tiebreakers .

```
using System;
using System.Data;

class Program {
  static string ReadLine { get { return Console.ReadLine(); } }
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.Out.Write(
     new DataTable().Compute(string.Join("\u002b", 
     ReadLine,
     ReadLine), "")
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 69

My attempt, using bitwise operators

`for(x=(z=prompt().split(" "))[0],y=z[1];y;)x^=y,y=(y&x^y)<<1;alert(x)`

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 44 bytes

```r
nchar(paste(strrep(" ",scan()),collapse=""))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py85I7FIoyCxuCRVo7ikqCi1QENJQUmnODkxT0NTUyc5PycnsaA41VZJSVPzv4WCyX8A)

Converts the two inputs to unary and "sums" via concatenation. Check out the other R answers:

- [Using `sequence`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4041/80010)
- [Using dot product](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4032/80010)

Answer (score 0):

## C, score 0 with 8 tie-breakers

```c
f(a,b) { return b ? f(a^b, a<<1 & b<<1) : a; }
 ^ ^ ^               ^   ^    ^      ^^
```

I've highlighted the tie-break chars.

Negative numbers are assumed to be 2s-complement.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (ES6) - 8 Tie-breaker characters

```
add: {
    let a = prompt``|false;
    let b = prompt``|false;
    while (a & b) {
        a = a ^ b;
        b = [b & ~a][false|false] << true
    }
    alert(a | b);
}
```

- 2 * `(`
- 2 * `)`
- 4 * `=`

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 12 bytes

```
IITM:{P}?trh
```

Thanks to JoKing for reminding me there was a Teleport Pad!!

**1st version, 25 bytes**

```
II!/M:{P}?\rh
   \     :/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39MzxNeqOqDWvqQIyDPmMjYBAA)

This was alot easier than I thought it would be!!! I will be golfing this alot more!!!

Comment: [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39MzxFclQMXKvkQFyDPmMjYBAA) using teleports, [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39MzQSvAwqBAAcg25jI2AQA) using put. Or [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39MzQT0ACJIMChSAXGMuYxMA) without tie breaker characters

Comment: @JoKing Wow. Those use strategies I wasn't even thinking of!!!, nice!

Answer (score 0):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), (no +/-, 1 tie-breaker, 11 bytes)

```
'V2,k!$wi|;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/189zEgnW1GlPLPG@v9/UwVzAA)

Not allowed to have `+` characters? Fine, I'll create them myself with math and reflection. `V` has the byte value 86, which gets divided by 2 (the `,` and only tie-breaker character) converted to a character, and finally, reflectively written into the program under the instruction pointer. It then reads `i`nput, hits a reflector (`|`), reads input again, then reaches the space originally containing a `w` and adds them together before printing. The IP then performs an illegal action at `,` and is silently terminated.

Is this cheating? Probably. But the challenge says "don't use `+` characters" and the *source code* contains 0 of them.

## Alternate method, (no +/-, 3 tie-breakers, 16 bytes)

```
"ab"1,i*}i*qul$;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/18pMUnJUCdTqzZTq7A0R8X6/39TBXMA)

Makes two strings, one of length `x` and one of length `y`, concatenates them together, then computes the length of the string. Does this count as a "sum-like function"? Perhaps. `+` on two strings does do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 4 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>, 0 `+`/`-`, 0 tie breakers

Can sum any number of non-negative integers.

```apl
≢⎕⌿#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94P@jzkWP@qY@6tmvDOL/VwCDAi4jBRMuGNsczjJWMFQwAQA)

`#` reference to the root object

`⎕/` replicate by the number(s) from STDIN
<sup>for each number, we get that many copies of the corresponding element on the right, but since there is only one, all numbers get paired up with that one, forming a single list of N<sub>1</sub>+N<sub>2</sub>+…+N<sub>n</sub> references</sup>

`≢` tally

Output is implicitly to STDOUT.

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 4 bytes, one +.

```
&&+.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X01NW@//f0MjYy4TUzMA)

Comment: Surely you could use `p` to place a `+` command?

Comment: @negativeseven I just made it for my Seed answer below.

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 3 bytes, 0 `+`/`-`

```
α▓∞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///cxkfTJj/qmPf/v6GRsYKJqRkA)

While perhaps violating the spirit of the "no `sum`" rule, this solution wraps the inputs into an array, calculates the average of the values in that array, and duplicates the result. Of course, the `avg` operator uses a `sum` internally, but its behavior is inherently different compared to the `sum` operator `Σ`.

The output is printed as a float, with `.0` at the end. If this is not acceptable, just add `i` to the end to convert it back into an integer.

### Explanation

```
α     wrap last two elements in array
 ▓    get average of list
  ∞   pop a, push 2*a
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 0 +/- characters, 0 tiebreaker characters, 47 bytes

```
brqzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzpyadgyacpyappyacybyabybay
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9PKiqswgQFlYkp6ZWJyUC6AIiTK5MqE5MqkxIr//83NzBSMDcyUAAA)

Made all out letters, because why not?

More readable variant that does pretty much the same thing:

```
b<@                               &&pyapyabybay
```

Abuses the `y` GetSysInfo command, which can be used to retrieve the instruction pointer's current X coordinate. This is used to push the ASCII codes for `+` (add) and `.` (output), which later get `p`ut onto the field.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 3 tiebreakers

I take no credit for this, as this is not an original answer, but merely an amalgamation of the following answers to this same challenge:

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5701/97511, https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4613/97511

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define OP (
#define CP )
#define CO ,

int main OP ac CO av CP int ac; typeof OP "" CP av; {
    scanf OP "%d\n%d" CO &ac CO &av CP;
    return printf OP "%d\n" CO &av[ac] CP;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzdCoJAEIXv9ykGRSmooB8iMLrpAfS@uhhmV1uoUXQVInr2zdHIuTvf@ebQsiDyPrRMj1YbODZO23J1PykVapNbNpBmMPuHcwbzKaSwUMqygydaFhFJIHbiCUdKwL0qU@bSBoFw7BJ4K@ivIeSxiPSVIx3IczxuxMNIMni1cW3NUNX95OT/7O6CdBvUj/frzVbt9ocv)

Answer (score 0):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 0 tie-breaker characters

```
say ½−½−$_ given ½−½−get−get
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVLh0N5HHZPAhEq8QnpmWWoeklB6agmE/P/fmMsEAA)

`−` here is the Unicode character MINUS SIGN at codepoint 8722, rather than the ASCII/Unicode character `-`, HYPHEN-MINUS, at codepoint 45.  The two are synonymous in Raku, but the former is by no stretch the "standard" subtraction operator.

`½−½−` is how I'm negating numbers without using any of the tiebreaking characters.  It could be done with just a single leading MINUS SIGN, but that could arguably be considered a "negation function."

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), no +/-, 1 tiebreaker

```julia
import Base:Meta.parse
["a"^[readline|>map|>parse][] "b"^[readline|>map|>parse][]]|>join|>length|>show
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/PzO3IL@oRMEpsTjVyje1JFGvILGoOJUrWilRKS66KDUxJSczL7XGLjexoMYOLBUbHauglIRbMrbGLis/M6/GLic1L70ko8auOCO//P9/QyNjLhMzi/8A)

- `"a"^N` creates a string of length N
- `x|>f` is equivalent to `f(x)`
- `f|>map` calls `f` with no argument (`f()`)
- `[...][]` is equivalent to parenthesis
- we join both strings and check for the total length

#### [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/) (function), no +/-, no tiebreaker

```julia
x->["a"^[x|>first][] "b"^[x|>last][]]|>join|>length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvu/QtcuWilRKS66osYuLbOouCQ2OlZBKQkikJMI5sfW2GXlZ@YB@al56SUZ/x2KM/LLFdI0og2NjHVMzCxiNf//BwA)